# Implement oauth login to salesforce app, but refresh token is coming undefined

Tags: node.js, oauth, salesforce, aws-lambda

I am working on AWS Lambda using node.js. I am using node-salesforce to connect to SF App using OAuth. I am not able to get refresh token after login.

```
var conn = new sf.Connection({
    oauth2 : {
        clientId : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        clientSecret : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        redirectUri : 'https://localhost/callback'
    }
});
conn.login('Username', 'XXXXXXXXX', function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(userInfo);
    console.log(conn);
});
```

In the output I am expecting a refresh Token that is coming undefined. I am able to get accessToken which I am using for further operation. Now how do i update access token in case of change of access token.

I have gone through its documentation(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-salesforce). It has a way in which they have used express.js and redirect to salesforce page for authorisation. Since this is written in lambda so I will not prefer to use express.js here or redirection for authorisation.

My problem is how to get refresh token here. Is there any way to do this. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a refresh token, you need to specify that you will be using this accessToken offline.  This is typically done via a header, but sometimes done via a URL param.